# Unity ads - not showing on phone

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ads

I'm trying to implement unity rewarded ads. They work fine in the editor. However when I run it on my phone, the ads don't show up. Nothing happens when I click on the show ads button. I have a very simple project. There is a button that has the ShowRewardedVideo() function assigned and an admanager script. Not sure what's going wrong. Can someone please help?

Here is the admanager script:

```
 string gameId = "123456";
 bool testM = true;
 string reward = "rewardedVideo";     

 void Start()
  {
    Advertisement.AddListener(this);
    Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, testM);
  }

 public void ShowRewardedVideo()
  {        
    if (Advertisement.IsReady(reward))
    {            
        Advertisement.Show(reward);            
    }        
  }

 public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string placementId, ShowResult showResult)
  {       
    if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished)
    {
        Debug.Log("got reward");
    }
    else if (showResult == ShowResult.Skipped)
    {
        // Do not reward the user for skipping the ad.
    }
    else if (showResult == ShowResult.Failed)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("The ad did not finish due to an error.");
    }
  }

 public void OnUnityAdsReady(string placementId)
  {        
    if (placementId == reward)
    {
      
    }
  }

 public void OnUnityAdsDidError(string message)
  {
    // Log the error.
  }

 public void OnUnityAdsDidStart(string placementId)
  {
    // Optional actions to take when the end-users triggers an ad.
  }

// When the object that subscribes to ad events is destroyed, remove the listener:
 public void OnDestroy()
  {
    Advertisement.RemoveListener(this);
  }
}
```